# Simplifying ToString() implementation

Tags: c#, strings

Any ideas?

```
public override string ToString() {
    string returnValue;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Country))
        returnValue = string.Format("{0}", Country);
    else
        return returnValue;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City))
        returnValue += string.Format(", city {0}", City);
    else
        return returnValue;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Street))
        returnValue += string.Format(", street {0}", Street);
    else
        return returnValue;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Block))
        returnValue += string.Format(", block {0}", Block);
    else
        return returnValue;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Building))
        returnValue += string.Format(", building {0}", Building);



    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Latitude) 
             && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Longitude))
    returnValue += string.Format(", coordinates {0}:{1}", Latitude, Longitude);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: You did notice that in all but the first case you are returning strings. But the first case `return Country` you are always returning a NULL or an empty string. In which case you may want to make that explicit `return string.empty` just to show that it is nothing that is being returned.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo. It must be  "return returnValue;"

Comment: @Alex About your Update: There are ways to simplify it, just depends on what you put a higher priority, readability/maintainability or performance etc etc. Your code looks easy to maintain but it could definitely be shorter Or run quicker ... did that make sense? So what exactly did you want simpler?

Comment: I do not know what is a higher priority. It's and a readbility and a perfomance.

Answer (score 2):

I find that writing it this way makes it more maintainable and relatively efficient.

```
public class Information
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Block { get; set; }
    public string Building { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<Tuple<string[], string>> DataFormatPairs()
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(new[] { Country },             "{0}");
        yield return Tuple.Create(new[] { City },                "city {0}");
        yield return Tuple.Create(new[] { Street },              "street {0}");
        yield return Tuple.Create(new[] { Block },               "block {0}");
        yield return Tuple.Create(new[] { Building },            "building {0}");
        yield return Tuple.Create(new[] { Latitude, Longitude }, "coordinates {0}:{1}");
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var data = DataFormatPairs()
            .TakeWhile(p => p.Item1.All(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)))
            .Select(p => String.Format(p.Item2, p.Item1));
        return String.Join(", ", data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using "&&" it will stop the evaluation at the first false, so something like this should work for you:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
    public string Long { get; set; }
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var tempVar =
            (AddPropertyData(sb, "{0}", Item1) &&
             AddPropertyData(sb, ", item2 {0}", Item2) &&
             AddPropertyData(sb, ", item3 {0}", Item3)) &&
             AddPropertyData(sb, ", long: {0}, lat: {1}", Long, Lat);

        return sb.Length > 0 ? sb.ToString() : Item1;
    }

    private static bool AddPropertyData(StringBuilder sb, string format, params string[] data)
    {
        if (data.All(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(format, data);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First question is, why isn't your `AddPropertyData` static? Then, what do you do with "coordinates" where the *single value* consists of *2 members* (latitude, longitude)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation:

```
public override string ToString() { 
    var list = new List<string>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Country)) 
        list.Add(string.Format("{0}", Country));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City)) 
        list.Add(string.Format("city {0}", City));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Street)) 
        list.Add(string.Format("street {0}", Street));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Block)) 
        list.Add(string.Format("block {0}", Block));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Building)) 
        list.Add(string.Format("building {0}", Building));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Latitude)  
             && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Longitude)) 
        list.Add(string.Format("coordinates {0}:{1}", Latitude, Longitude));

    return list.Count > 0 ? String.Join(", ", list.ToArray()) : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and my code?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string returnValue = string.empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Country))
            return returnValue;    // Note: this is a change from the original code
                                   // That could have returned NULL. But I think the
                                   // intent of the function is to always return some
                                   // form of string.


        returnValue = string.Format("{0}", Country);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City))
            return returnValue;

        returnValue += string.Format(", city {0}", City);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Street))
            return returnValue;

        returnValue += string.Format(", street {0}", Street);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Block))
            return returnValue;

        returnValue += string.Format(", block {0}", Block);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Building))
            returnValue += string.Format(", building {0}", Building);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Latitude) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Longitude))
            returnValue += string.Format(", coordinates {0}:{1}", Latitude, Longitude);

        return returnValue;
    }
```

If you want to compress this slightly. Though I am in two minds weather this is worth it or not:

```
public class Pair
{
    public Pair(string v, string f) { this.Value =v; this.Format = f;}    
    public string Value  { get; private set; }
    public string Format { get; private set; }
};

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string returnValue = string.empty;

        string[] address = {new Pair(Country, "{0}"),
                            new Pair(City,    ", city {0}"),
                            new Pair(Street,  ", street {0}"),
                            new Pair(Block,   ", block {0}")
                           };

        foreach(Pair loop in address)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loop.Value))
                return returnValue;

            returnValue += string.Format(loop.Format, loop.Value);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Building))
            returnValue += string.Format(", building {0}", Building);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Latitude) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Longitude))
            returnValue += string.Format(", coordinates {0}:{1}", Latitude, Longitude);

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: -1: I posted 2 answers in this topic and your answer is **exact** duplicate of what I recommend.

Comment: Moreover, using `string` for appending is a bad practice - it's way slower than `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @loki2302: I'll take the -1 for not using StringBuilder. But don't vote people down because they have the same idea as you. Anyway this code is superior to yours in the maintainability field. Yours fails on the front that you are trying to hard to be clever and it makes the code less readable.

Comment: The idea of this site is to have questions and answers. I see no reason in having the same answer for the same question twice. Read before you post - it's about 3 hours between mine and yours: you had a chance to see that everything you wanted to say has already been said. Not also sure why you think your code is more maintainable: redundant class, redundant logic. My approach is short, stupid and it works. It's really easy to understand and modify. I see no reason why someone might want to have extra `if`s when the problem is easily solvable with less code and less logic.

Comment: I can add 10 more comments like: why is your 'Pair' not `sealed`? and even why is it `public`? why do you use bad names like `v` and `f`? Why do you use that strange formatting? why there are 2 returns in your `ToString()`? I don't think your code is *really* better by any mean.

Comment: Just a brief summary: in my solution, there's 1 explicit loop and 1 explicit `if`. What's about yours? Less logic, less problems.

Comment: @loki2302: If you think yours is so much better than why go to the effort of burrying mine. Just allow the general reader to vote on them as appropriate. Now that I re-read yours I see that mine is nowhere near the same so you have nothing to complain about. It is still a worse solution. Yours would not pass a decent code review. By failing the too clever by half rule and is thus not maintainable.

Comment: I'm not trying to say mine is better, I just see complexity and redundancies in yours. Re-read your code.